# Making a input field able to be filled in more then once

Tags: javascript, html, api, input

For my school project I am using a pokemon API to show te user a pokomon when they type in the pokemons name. I got it working that it will show the pokemon that the user typed in but after that the input field is gone. I want the user to be able to fill the input field again and also show the correct pokemon then en not the previous.

The html code I use:

```
    <div class="pokemon">
        <h3>Vul hier uw liefelings pokemon in en kom meer over hem/haar te weten.</h3>
        <input type="text" id="pokemon">
        <button onclick="selectPokemonName()">Submit</button>
        <div id="poke_container" class="poke-container"></div>
        <div class="pokemon">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The JS code I use for this is:

```
function selectPokemonName() {

  var pokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemon").value;

  const apiData = {
  url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/',
  type: 'pokemon',
  id: pokemonName,
  }

const {url, type, id} = apiData

const apiUrl = `${url}${type}/${id}`

fetch(apiUrl)
    .then( (data) => {
        if(data.ok){
            return data.json()
        }
        throw new Error('Response not ok.'); 
    })
    .then( pokemon => generateHtml(pokemon))
    .catch( error => console.error('Error:', error))
}


const generateHtml = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    const html = `
        <div class="name">${data.name}</div>
        <img src=${data.sprites.front_default}>
        <div class="details">
            <span>Height: ${data.height}</span>
            <span>Weight: ${data.weight}</span>
        </div>

    `
    const pokemonDiv = document.querySelector('.pokemon')
    pokemonDiv.innerHTML = html
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L3mdbx4r/

Comment: const pokemonDiv = document.querySelector('.pokemon')[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fetching the Pokemon data you query for the element with the classname `.pokemon`. (`document.querySelector('.pokemon')`). You actually have two elements with that classname; your outer div as well as another children div.

`document.querySelector` returns only the first found element, and in your case that is the outer element. `innerHTML` overwrites the existing HTML.

Instead you should query for a single unique container, and it seems you already have that:

```js
const pokemonContainer = document.querySelector('#poke_container')
pokemonContainer.innerHTML = html
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked! You know if there is a way to display 10 different pokemons random generated?

Answer (score 0):

Restructure you html so you have separate area to search for items and place requested content

**Example**

```js
const pokemonInput = document.querySelector("#pokemon");
const button = document.querySelector(".pokemon__button");
const content = document.querySelector('.pokemon__result')
const apiData = {
  url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/',
  type: 'pokemon'
}

button.addEventListener("click", ({
  target: {
    value: pokemonName
  }
}) => {
  selectPokemon(pokemonName)
})

const getPokemon = (url) => Promise.resolve({
  name: 'Pikachu',
  sprites: {
    front_default: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/25.png'
  },
  height: 1,
  weight: 1

})

function selectPokemon(pokemonName) {

  const {
    url,
    type
  } = apiData

  const apiUrl = `${url}${type}/${pokemonName}`

  getPokemon(apiUrl)
    .then(pokemon => {
      generateHtml(pokemon)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
}


const generateHtml = ({
  name,
  sprites,
  height,
  weight
}) => {
  const html = `
        <div class="name">${name}</div>
        <img src=${sprites.front_default}>
        <div class="details">
            <span>Height: ${height}</span>
            <span>Weight: ${weight}</span>
        </div>

    `

  content.innerHTML = html
}
```

```html
<div class="pokemon">
  <div class="pokemon__search">
    <input type="text" id="pokemon" placeholder="Enter pokemon name...">
    <button class="pokemon__button">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="pokemon__result">
  </div>
</div>
```